# Finding error in running emulator

Tags: java, android

I am new to android programming and when I am trying to run an emulator it says the following error:

> missing feature watch

What is this error and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Answer (score 1):

Your application is for both

> Mobile
>
> Wearable

But the emulator you created doesn't support wearable!

[image]